# How to set background image with 300DPI/PPI resolution for A5 format report

Tags: jasper-reports

i need to set an image background for my report.

The problem is my image has 300DPI/PPI resolutions and a REAL dimension of A5 paper, and my report has a page format of A5 (14,85x21 cm) at 72 DPI are only 421x595 pixel...

I have to use the image for the background of my report.

So, how can i add my image scanned from a REAL image to background if my report, if it has a resolution of only 72 DPI?

Answer (score 0):

Open the photo in any photo editor and save it as 72 DPI. Unless you want to always use different images from scanner to be used as the report background.